# One Input - two styles? Left side cursor:text, right side cursor:pointer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a way (using javascript/jQuery) to do following:

On my page, I have one input type=text. This input has a background-image on its right side.

```
<input id="my-input" type="text" value="foobar" style="background-image:url(path/to/my/image.gif); background-position:right center; background-repeat:no-repeat; height:17px; width:97px;"/>
```

When the cursor moves over the background-image (width:21px), the cursor icon should be set to pointer. Otherwise it should be cursor:text.

I have to use the input! I am not able to create a new div next to the input for this icon!

I tried to solve this problem like this:

```
$('#my-input').mousemove(function (event) {
    this.style.cursor = ((event.offsetX || event.layerX) < this.offsetWidth - 21) ? "text" : "pointer";
});
```

But this won't work. `this.offsetWidth - 21` has the right value but `event.layerX` and `event.offsetX` is undefined.

Do you have another idea, how to solve this problem? Can you tell me, why my js won't work as I want it to do?

Comment: tested and working on Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/LVG7S/

Comment: Wow, it does work in Chrome and Firefox and IE. So, what is the problem?

Comment: `eventObject.offsetX/Y` is not cross browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this way and its working (tested on IE). Check out [**here**](http://jsbin.com/oduhi4/edit).

```
$('#my-input').mousemove(function (event) { 

  $(this).css("cursor", ((event.offsetX || event.layerX) < this.offsetWidth - 21) ? "text" : "pointer");

 });
```

Comment: you are right. this is working.
so, I have to look for my error in my other code.

Answer (score 0):

Mouse position is one of those problems I always look up. Here is one [solution](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Mouse_Position). Notice in particular that halfway down is a snippet that shows how to determine the mouse position relative to the upper left corner of the object in question (e.g. a text field). That may be relevant to solving your problem.

Maybe something like the following would work

```
$('#my-input').mousemove(function(e) {
    var pos = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    this.style.cursor = (pos < this.offsetWidth - 21) ? 'text' : 'pointer';
});
```